# How to customize keybinding when application is not in focus

Tags: java, swing, action, awt, key-bindings

My objective is to customize the `PrintScreen` key`binding.

However, I need my application to be out of focus for it to work.
I am using inputmap and actionmap to do this. The parameter I am using is `Component.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`. Given below is my code but it is not working.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jButton1.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke
        .getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN,2),"ps");
    jButton1.getActionMap().put("ps",new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            //int i;
            i++;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
     });
}
```

If not keybinding then how can I customize a keystroke response when application is not in focus?

Comment: Key Bindings only work when your application has focus.

Comment: really don't understood for reason, simple impossible, application's window must have a focus on the screen on each Native OS, maybe you have two or more JFrames / JDialog, I think that you have up_date your question for more details about ...

Comment: If not keybinding then how can I customize a keystroke response when application is not in focus?

Comment: no way (without native code) - the app doesn't get any keystrokes from the OS

Answer (score 3):

The highest level `InputMap` is `Component.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`, which, as it says, works when the `Component` is in the focused window. If your window is not focused, you will not get any input events.

Also, in your example, you are not passing an argument to `getInputMap`, so you are getting the default one (`Component.WHEN_FOCUSED`).

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to leverage [`setDefaultButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html#setDefaultButton%28javax.swing.JButton%29), which is bound the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key by default. Several complete examples are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A230513%20setDefaultButton); see also [*How to Use Key Bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). For example,

```
JButton send = new JButton("Send");
…
f.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(send);
```